# Tracking sales from campaigns of an app with facebook sdk

Tags: facebook, sdk, tracking

- I have an app with integrated Facebook sdk.
- I can monitor app installs in facebook analytics.
- I created a campaign, which runs for a week now. I am pretty sure, that the campaign triggered sales, because sales went up.

BUT : I can't see app installs in campaign. I mean in facebook analytics I see the sales (Means SDK implementation in my app works with the installevent sent to facebook), but not in my campagn. 
What else do I need to do to track app installs related to my campaigns ?

[image]

Comment: Nobody that can help ? Answer can also be, that it is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

in your facebook developer account, in your facebook app settings page, have you supplied the bundle identifier, and the Apple-ID of your app?
Are you working with suffixes? I am currently experiencing issues with suffixes.

Comment: I have added the bundlename and apple-id as documented from Facebook. My Bundle has the format : com.company.appname. Its still not tracking installs for my campaigns. Any hints ?

Comment: I actually get the message "Application in Developer Mode (Sandbox Mode):  To promote this application, please publish the application on the developer site." when creating a new AD. I already created an AD for the same app without problems, but there must be any change recently. COuld that be the problem and what exactly do I have to do ?

Comment: I published the app in facebook. Now with a new campaign its working. What was confusing is, that I could start a campaign without publishing 2 weeks ago. Seems facebook made a change meanwhile.